# i have problem in accuracy when i merge 2 cnn to binary classification for 1D data

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

i  have problem in accuracy when i merge 2 cnn to binary classification for 1D data
the code

```
history = model_combined.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64,verbose = 1,validation_data=(X_test,Y_test))
```

`ValueError: Layer \"model_9\" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 12) dtype=float32>]\n"`

Comment: Please edit your question to improve readability.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I've edited your question to improve the readability. For future reference, please read [code formatting help](/editing-help#code). See also [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.